# How to loop through a list of objects and search for a string in C#

Tags: c#, list, oop, for-loop, foreach

I've created an app where you can add students and lecturers to a list of each, and I need to search the lists to find a student or lecturer by name or ID. However, when I'm looping through the list to find a matching string, it will find the matching string and print the details, but the else statement saying student not found is getting triggered for each other member of the list. I tried putting a break after the if statement, but it still happens. How do I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DBSManagement
{
    class College: Staff
    {
        public static List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        public static List<Lecturer> lecturers = new List<Lecturer>();

        static void Main()
        { 
            int choice;
            bool seeAgain = true;

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press");
                    Console.WriteLine("1: To add a student");
                    Console.WriteLine("2: To add a lecturer");
                    Console.WriteLine("3: To search for a lecturer or student");
                    Console.WriteLine("4: To show the details of all enrolled students");
                    Console.WriteLine("5: To show the names of all lecturers");
                    Console.WriteLine("6: To show payroll details for a lecturer");
                    Console.WriteLine("7: To quit");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);

                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            AddStudent();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            AddLecturer();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            SearchPerson();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ShowStudents();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            ShowLecturers();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            ShowPayrollDetails();
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            seeAgain = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option selected");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (seeAgain);
            }
        public static void AddStudent()
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student name:");
            student.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student address:");
            student.Address = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student phone number:");
            student.Phone = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student email:");
            student.Email = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student PPSN:");
            student.PPSN = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student status (postgrad or undergrad):");
            EnterStat:
                string stat = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (stat == "postgrad" || stat == "undergrad")
                {
                    student.Status = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), stat);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter either postgrad or undergrad:");
                goto EnterStat;
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student ID:");
            int inStudentID;
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inStudentID);
            student.StudentID = inStudentID;
            students.Add(student);
        }

        public static void AddLecturer()
        {
            Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer name:");
            lecturer.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer address:");
            lecturer.Address = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer phone number:");
            lecturer.Phone = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer email:");
            lecturer.Email = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer PPSN:");
            lecturer.PPSN = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer ID:");
            lecturer.ID = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter salary:");
            lecturer.Salary = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter subject taught:");
            lecturer.SubjectTaught = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            lecturers.Add(lecturer);
        }

        public static void SearchPerson()
        {
            int searchChoice = 0;
            int studentSearch = 0;
            int lecturerSearch = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Press:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 to search for a student");
            Console.WriteLine("2 to search for a lecturer");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out searchChoice);

            switch (searchChoice)
            {
                //search students
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Press:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1 to search by name");
                    Console.WriteLine("2 to search by student number");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out studentSearch);

                    switch (studentSearch)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter student name:");
                            string studentNameSearch = Console.ReadLine();

                            foreach (Student student in students)
                                //(int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (student.Name.Contains(studentNameSearch))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(student.ToString());
                                    break;
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Student name not found");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            int studentIDSearch;
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter student number:");
                            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out studentIDSearch);

                            for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (students[i].StudentID == studentIDSearch)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(students[i].ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Student number not found");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option selected");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                //search lecturers
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Press:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1 to search by name");
                    Console.WriteLine("2 to search by course taught");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out lecturerSearch);

                    switch (lecturerSearch)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer name:");
                            string lecturerNameSearch = Console.ReadLine();
                            for (int i = 0; i < lecturers.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (lecturers[i].Name == lecturerNameSearch)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(lecturers[i].ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Lecturer name not found");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter course taught:");
                            string lecturerSubjectSearch = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                            for (int i = 0; i < lecturers.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (lecturers[i].SubjectTaught == lecturerSubjectSearch)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(lecturers[i].ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Subject not found");
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option selected");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid option selected");
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void ShowStudents()
        {
            //sort list by name
            List<Student> SortedStudents = students.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();

            foreach (Student student in SortedStudents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student);
            }
        }

        public static void ShowLecturers()
        {
            //sort list by name
            List<Lecturer> SortedLecturers = lecturers.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();

            foreach (Lecturer lecturer in SortedLecturers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lecturer.Name);
            }
        }

        public static void ShowPayrollDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter lecturer name:");
            string lecturerNameSearch = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < lecturers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (lecturers[i].Name == lecturerNameSearch)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lecturers[i].PayrollDetails());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lecturer name not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes, save yourself a lot of unnecessary line of code and use LINQ.

Comment: static List<Student> matchingStudents  = students.Where(s => s.Name = searchVal).toList();

Comment: I don't know what Linq is, I'm in college and they haven't mentioned it. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
            Boolean found = false;
            foreach (Student student in students)
            //(int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
            {
                if (student.Name.Contains(studentNameSearch))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(student.ToString());
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found == false)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Student name not found");
            }​
```

Comment: I tried this but it's claiming that found is defined but never used.

Comment: The warning doesn't make any sense.  Did you copy code correctly?

Comment: I didn't think it made sense. Pretty sure I copied correctly though. I tried it again and it's giving me an unexpected character error for the close bracket of the second if statement. Makes even less sense.

Comment: I deleted the symbol and retyped it and it's not throwing the error anymore. And your solution works! Don't know why Visual was kicking up a fuss.

Answer (score 1):

Your code outputs "Student name not found" for each element `student` in your list which

- does not satisfy the condition `student.Name.Contains(studentNameSearch)` and
- preceeds the first element in the list that satisfies the condition (if such an element exists, otherwise the message is printed for each element in the list).

You can only be sure that there is no student satisfying the condition *after* searching through the entire list.

A possible solution:

```
Student studentMatch = null;
foreach (Student student in students)
{
    if (student.Name.Contains(studentNameSearch))
    {
         studentMatch = student;
         break;
    }
}      
if (studentMatch == null)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Student name not found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(studentMatch.ToString());
}
```